# I want to allow only 1 radio button every time

Tags: html, css, types, radio-button

Im using radio buttons, and I dont want that the user can select multiple radio buttons. But its not working, the user can select both radio buttons everytime.

Ja = Yes, nee = No.
I want to make the user decide between either Yes or no. Nothing else.

```
     <p>Vraag 13: Houdt u van wijnproeferijen?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag13ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag13nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 14: Houdt u van restaurants?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag14ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag14nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 15: Houdt u van nieuwe mensen ontmoeten?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag15ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag15nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 16: Houdt u van cafes?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag16ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag16nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 17: Houdt u van een feestje?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag17ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag17nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 18: Houdt u van nieuwe culturen ontdekken?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag18ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag18nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 19: Houdt u van bergwandelen?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag19ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag19nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 20: Houdt u van sportwedstrijden?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag20ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag20nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 21: Houdt u van oude gebouwen bezoeken?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag21ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag21nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 22: Houdt u ervan om nationale monumenten te bezoeken?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag22ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag22nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 23: Houdt u van watersport?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag23ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag23nee" value="nee"> Nee
        <p>Vraag 24: Houdt u van sporten?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="vraag24ja" value="ja"> Ja
        <input type="radio" id="vraag24nee" value="nee"> Nee

    </div>
```

Comment: Radio groups have to share a name attribute. Right now they are not grouped together. I would suggest you check out the spec's on radio buttons.

Comment: @scrappedcola How do I do so? Im kinda new in this world haha

Answer (score 1):

From the [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) reference of radio buttons:

> Note: The radio group must have share the same name (the value of the
> name attribute) to be treated as a group. Once the radio group is
> created, selecting any radio button in that group automatically
> deselects any other selected radio button in the same group. You can
> have as many radio groups on a page as you want, as long as each group
> has its own name.

Yo might want to use the label tag as well. For example:

```
<p>Vraag 13: Houdt u van wijnproeferijen?</p>
<input type="radio" name="first" id="vraag13ja" value="ja">
<label for="vraag13ja">Ja</label>
<input type="radio" name="first" id="vraag13nee" value="nee">
<label for="vraag13nee">Nee</label><br>

<p>Vraag 14: Houdt u van restaurants?</p>
<input type="radio" name="second" id="vraag14ja" value="ja">
<label for="vraag14ja">Ja</label>
<input type="radio" name="second" id="vraag14nee" value="nee"> Nee
<label for="vraag14nee">Nee</label>
```

...and so on